# How to float image inside of div

Tags: css, position, css-float

I have this html:

```
<div class="speaker-list">
    <div class="view-content">
        <div class="views-row views-row-1 views-row-odd views-row-first">   
            <div class="views-field views-field-title">
                <span class="field-content">
                    <a href="/speaker/keith-anderson">Keith Anderson</a>
                </span>
            </div>  
            <div class="views-field views-field-field-job-title">
                <div class="field-content">VP, Digital Advisory</div>
            </div>  
            <div class="views-field views-field-field-company">
                <div class="field-content">RetailNet Group</div>
            </div>  
            <div class="views-field views-field-title-1">
                <span class="field-content">
                    <a href="/session/store">Store of the Future</a>
                </span>
            </div>  
            <div class="views-field views-field-field-headshot">
                <div class="field-content">
                    <div id="file-53" class="file file-image file-image-jpeg contextual-links-region"> 
                        <div class="content">
                            <img typeof="foaf:Image" src="/kanderson.jpg" width="180" height="180" alt="" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
             </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

It's dynamically generated by a Drupal view, so I can't change the output html at all. I need to work with what is here. Here's the desired result:

[image]

Without any styling on the headshot, this is what it looks like:
[image]

I tried to style the image to force it to float to the left of the text:

```
.view-speaker-list div.view-content div.views-row div.views-field
div.field-content div.file-image div.content img {
    border: 1px solid #666;
    float: left;
    position: relative; /* tried with and without position (inc. absolute) */
    left: 30px;
}
```

Obviously I'm doing something wrong, because this is what I get (with relative position):
[image]

and with absolute position:
[image]

I've also tried putting the float on the "uppermost" div class that holds the image, with no position on the div:

```
.view-speaker-list div.view-content div.views-row
div.views-field-field-headshot {
    float: left;
}
```

It gives the same result as the position: relative screenshot.

Where am I going wrong? If I had control over the html I'd do it differently, but I'm not sure how to deal with all of these nested divs.

**EDITED TO ADD NEW SCREENSHOT FOR @WEX**

Here's what it looks like when I tried to use your code with the html reordered - http://jsfiddle.net/mPa7z/

[image]

Comment: Is the image size fixed? If not, you're gonna have a bad time. Why can't you just change the Drupal view?

Comment: Yes, the image size is fixed. And unfortunately we have corporate standards in place about views...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll try to explain the "right" way to use `float` so that you can see why your way didn't work.

In your post, you try to apply `float: left` to the `<div>` surrounding your image, but that technique only works when the element you are floating is above all the elements you want to wrap around it. That "may" solve your problem, but that technique has it's pitfalls if you're trying to use it to create two distinct columns - if the text on the right is taller than the floated element, the text on the right will wrap below it. So then you have to add another container around your non-floated elements to ensure that it won't wrap. This solves your problem, but doesn't really help if you can't even edit your markup!

I'd argue that the technique I've posted below works better, and solves your problem: http://jsfiddle.net/Wexcode/AQQwX/

```
.view-content { 
    position: relative;
    min-height: 180px;
    padding: 0 0 0 180px; }
.views-row { padding: 20px 0 0 20px; }
.views-field-field-headshot {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0; }​
```

Comment: Seems reasonable. I hope that the assumptions you've made about the image size turn out to be acceptable.

Comment: Good point. Originally I had posted a comment asking if there were any restrictions in size, but then I noticed this in the OP's markup: `<img typeof="foaf:Image" src="/kanderson.jpg" width="180" height="180" alt="" />`, so I guess I just made an assumption. Who knows though, even those numbers might be dynamically generated.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed info. I'm a backend developer, and css is something I learn in bits and pieces when I need it. I'm fine with fonts, borders, backgrounds, etc., but positioning is something I've never really understood. Can you recommend a good reference/tutorial?

Comment: So I tried to combine your style info with the suggestion from @chipcullen below (I can definitely change the order of elements, just can't affect the default style output. I didn't realize having the headshot image first would make a difference.) In jFiddle it looks close to correct, but on my actual screen it doesn't. Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mPa7z/ - I'm adding another screenshot to the OP. You'll notice that only one headshot is visible, even though the others are obviously there in the rendered source.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to the View itself in Drupal, you *can reorder the elements*. When logged into Drupal, open the View (in Drupal 7: Structure > Views > Viewname), look for "Fields" and  click on the triangle next to "add", which will have a popup, then click "rearrange". You can then drag the photo field to be the first item in the View, then adjust your CSS to float the image to the left.

Comment: I do have access to the views; I can change the order of the fields, just not add any styles or change the wrapper html or anything that you can do in views. Positioning is the one part of css that I really have never gotten, and I didn't realize that having the fields in a different order would make a difference. I'll try that.

Comment: You shouldn't need to alter the HTML (though, even that is possible with a .tpl file) - but you may have to experiment with floating particular elements. In your case, there may be a `<div>` that is a parent of the image, and *that* will have to be floated to the left, not the image. It has to do with the fact that `<div>`'s are block level elements, so without floating, it would cause everything after it to go to the next line.

Answer (score 0):

EmmyS,

Instead of trying to get the headshot to `float:left`, have you considered making the others `float:right`? This will give the impression that the image is floating left without having to change the markup in any way.

```
div.speaker-list div.views-row > div.views-field {
    float:right;
    clear:both;
}
div.speaker-list div.views-row > div.views-field.views-field-field-headshot {
    float:none;
    clear:none;
}
```

The above CSS should work with that specific configuration without altering any of your other Drupal generated markup. In order to make sure that other CSS does not interfere, I've applied as much specificity as possible. Since the headshot will be back in the containing `<div>`, you shouldn't need to alter the size of it unless the store is simply too large (I don't know without looking at your data). Finally the CSS is concise, so you can add any additional styling you need on a per-element basis.

Hope this helps,

FuzzicalLogic

Comment: that's the worst css I've ever seen

Answer (score -1):

When you can drop somewhere else on the page some code, you can gain control over the HTML by using jQuery. Then you could make modifications to the DOM tree.

But I do not understand why you can not edit the HTML. Isn't Drupal open source? You should be able to find the file using FTP and manipulate it.

Comment: Hacking core Drupal files is NOT recommended.

Comment: More of a comment than an answer.

Comment: Yes, Drupal is open-source. But a) as @SomeKittens mentioned, hacking core is a bad idea, and b) our corporate standards require us to stick to the default classes provided by the views.