# CSS issues with nested divs and classes used in multiple levels

Tags: css, css-selectors

(Before I start, yes I have asked a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10940422/how-to-float-image-inside-of-div) before; unfortunately due to new information being added, the markup has completely changed for the worse, and it's now impossible for me to figure out.)

I have some very ugly markup generated by a Drupal view. Because many of the class names can be used in multiple places, in various levels of the hierarchy (for example, the first `view-content/view-grouping/view-grouping-header` needs to float left (or at least the contents of it do for the headshot image, but the other view-grouping-header elements need to display to the right of the image), I can't just address the class names; I need to get the full hierarchy. I'm having some trouble with that... (I know someone is going to come along and say, "but you can add classes to fields in Drupal views; why not do that?" Well, you can if you're displaying individual fields, but in this case I need to group by 5 of the 6 fields that are displayed, and when you group by a field you set the field itself to be excluded from the display, which means any custom classes you add to the field are ignored. The only thing you can do stylewise with grouping is apply a single class to all rows, which I've done but doesn't help in this case.)

```
<div class="view-clone-of-speaker-list">
<div class="view-content">
<div class="view-grouping">
    <div class="view-grouping-header">
        <div id="file-741" class="file file-image file-image-jpeg 
         contextual-links-region">
            <div class="content">
                <img src="johndoe.jpg" width="180" height="180" alt="" /> 
                <!-- this img needs to float left -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="view-grouping-content">
        <div class="view-grouping">
            <div class="view-grouping-header">
                <a href="/speaker/john-doe">John Doe</a>
                <!-- this view-grouping-header a needs to be styled differently 
                than the one the next level down (view full profile) -->
            </div>

            <div class="view-grouping-content">
                <div class="view-grouping">
                    <div class="view-grouping-header">
                        Freelance consultant
                    </div>
                    <div class="view-grouping-content">
                        <div class="view-grouping">
                            <div class="view-grouping-header">
                                Path to Purchase Institute
                            </div>
                            <div class="view-grouping-content">
                                <div class="view-grouping">
                                    <div class="view-grouping-header">
                                        <a href="/speaker/john-doe">
                                    view full profile    &gt;</a>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="view-grouping-content">
                                        <h3>Sessions:</h3>
                                        <div class="views-row views-row-1 views-row-odd views-row-first">      
                                            <div class="views-field views-field-title-1">
                                                <span class="field-content">
                                                    <a href="/session/keynote-address-2">Keynote Address 2</a>
                                                </span>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="views-row views-row-2 views-row-even views-row-last">      
                                            <div class="views-field views-field-title-1">
                                                <span class="field-content">
                                                    <a href="/session/keynote-address-1">Keynote Address 1</a>
                                                </span>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

This is what I've tried, for example, to get the outer view-grouping - I want to put a border around the entire thing:

```
.view-clone-of-speaker-list.div.view-content.div.view-grouping {
    border: 1px solid #a8a8a8;      
}
```

But according to Firebug the element is not getting that style.

Here's the desired outcome; I don't need help (I don't think!) with the actual style code; I just need a hand figuring out how to address the correct elements given how frakkin' awfully they're nested. 
[image]

Comment: I didn't actually read much of the post, but just for kicks and giggles, try adding !important after the css rule. So it'd be `.view-clone-of-speaker-list.div.view-content.div.view-grouping {
    border: 1px solid #a8a8a8 !important;    
}` That'll tell you if its a matter of specificity or not. If that works, it just means that the style is getting overridden by a parent style.

Comment: I don't even need to do that. I can check the element in Firebug to see which classes it's inheriting, and the only classes this is getting are from the user agent stylesheet - nothing from any kind of parent style.

Comment: Well, for one thing, you need to take out the first .div in your style selector. This is because something.somethingelse looks for an element of class "somethingelse" ***inside*** "something". Such an element doesn't exist in your architecture. So .view-clone-of-speaker-list.div.view-content would look for a .view-content *inside* a div *inside* view-clone-whatever

Comment: Philip: Um, no.  .something.somethingelse looks for an element with class "something" that also has a class of "somethingelse".  Adding dots is only a way to add more classes, not to go inside of something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A period on a selector means "class"; div.myClass means a div with a class of myClass.  div.myClass.div.myOtherClass doesn't mean anything.

I think what you want is

```
div.view-clone-of-speaker-list>div.view-content>div.view-grouping {
    border: 1px solid #a8a8a8;      
}
```

That means "a div with a class of view-grouping, which is a child of a div with a class of view-content, which is a child of a div with a class of view-clone-of-speaker-list".

Comment: I had tried that first. Doesn't work - there are too many classes that nest in different ways at different places. According to [this](http://css-tricks.com/multiple-class-id-selectors/), if you have a space between your elements, it finds ALL items that are descendents at ANY level, which obviously doesn't work here. I need to be able to address the exact configuration of divs and classes at every point.

Comment: And this was one of the simple ones - to get to the company name, for example, I need to do something like this (obviously not exactly this, since it's not working) `div.view-clone-of-speaker-list div.view-content div.view-grouping div.view-grouping-content div.view-grouping div.view-grouping-content div.view-grouping div.view-grouping-content div.view-grouping div.view-grouping-header {}`

Comment: To clarify, if I use your version, the styles DO get applied, but they end up "crossing over", if that makes any sense, from level to level. So the border gets applied to EVERY div that has the view-grouping class, which I don't want.

Comment: OK, I have changed my answer to specify direct children rather than descendants.